# How to capture job status with python multiprocessing.Process

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing

(Using Python 3.4)

This question is about identifying the completion of jobs ran using multiprocessing.Process and send the end result of the job to another function for further processing.

I'm using multiprocessing.Process to run 6 unix jobs in parallel. All 6 jobs are submitted using a shell script as ./runme where runme is simple shell script having a command line calling a tool.

```
#!/bin/csh
nc run -r CPUS/4 -- qrc -cmd designname.ccl
```

nc is something like bsub

End result of this run creates a text file which will be consumed by another post processing script.

My existing Python code has the following logic:

```
def sub_runqrc (designname, outputdir):
    qrcrun_process = subprocess.Popen("./"+runme, shell+true, cwd=designdir, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    for line in qrcrun_process.stdout:
         ### grep for Job ID ###
         return_dict.update({designname:<jobID>})
    return (return_dict)


#Main function logic
for line in designlist:
    #### designlist is a file and it has six names in it ####
    #### other logic #####
    qrc_processes = multiprocessing.Process(target=sub_runqrc, args=(line, testcase_dir))
    qrc_jobs.append(qrc_processes)
    qrc_processes.start()
for proc in qrc_jobs:
    proc.join()
```

From the above logic each process is done as soon as Job Id is collected. But actually another tool is continuing its work on the farm. How do I know if the status of the job is done? And call another function to start the post processing as soon the output text file is available.

I'm currently using a periodic function every 15mins to check the status of the job using a command similar to bjobs (on "nc" it is nc info jobId) but the job info is unavailable on the server as soon as job finished.

What is the best way to find out if the job is finished? Is there a way I can capture the exit code kind of thing into a variable in main function and call pass the designname to another function to start post processing the output file?

```
def sub_postprocess (designname, output.txt, outputdir):
    ### Run post process ####

    return ("Post processing done for "+designname)
```

Is using multiprocessing.Process the correct way or these kind of jobs has to be submitted in other ways?

Note: I Started writing code in python 15days ago. Struggling to understand classes and multiprocesses. Any suggestions/reccommedations?

In case if my question is not clear please let me know.

Comment: So you want to pass back a "completion" type notification to your main thread that the job being run in the subprocess is complete?

Comment: Yes, Correct. From the runme file I created the last line of the file is more like a bsub command. It returns a jobId and runs the job on a remote server. I'm currently returning the jobid and jobname in a dictionary format from sub_runqruc. But I'm wondering if sub_runqruc can wait until the job on the remote server is executed completely and return to main function for further processing.